# Selecting added images for css manipulation with jQuery.find doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have written this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var people = '<li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/"></li>';
      people += '<li><span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/300/200/"></span></li>';
      var $images = $(people);
      $('ul').prepend(people);
      $images.find('img').css({
        'display': 'none'
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/300/300/">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/300/300/">
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add new images (added when document is ready now, later through ajax) and then manipulate them by modifying some CSS property, but I can't get it to work even in this simple example.

`$images.find('img')` works but the chained `.css({'display':'none'});` doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var people = '<li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/"></li>';
      people += '<li><span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/300/200/"></span></li>';

  var $images = $(people);  
  $images.find('img').css('display', 'none');

  // or $images.find('img').css({'display': 'none'});

  $('ul').prepend($images);
});
```

[http://jsbin.com/dozapi/1/](http://jsbin.com/dozapi/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

`$images` holds elements that are not yet in the DOM - modifying their `display` property won't have any visible effects.

You can instead do:

```
...
$('ul').prepend(people).find('img').css({
    display: 'none'
});
```

Comment: That will hide all the images, I think OP wants to hide the images added throguh jQuery.

Comment: The images **are** in DOM, because OP used `.prepend(people)` before.

Comment: yes @techfoobar I need to only manipulate the images added through jQuery, your solution hides all the img in ul

Comment: @MartinErnst - Actually no. The images are in the DOM yes, but the image elements in the jQuery object held by the variable `images` are not.

Comment: @techfoobar You are totally right. The images prepended to the `ul` by `.prepend(people)` are **not the same** as the images in `$images`